# Can I Install 4.0.3 apk file in android phone with 2.2.1

Tags: android

I have my app developed in *android 4.0.3* in eclipse and I have exported it to create an apk file, but I am not able to install it in my Samsung Galaxy S2 with *android version 2.2.1*.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is Forward Compatible not Backward Compatible. So If you have made an application in 4.X and want in 2.X then it won't be possible.

This is a Link for you to find the [Levels of API](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `minSdkVersion` to API level 8 or lower. In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

And [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) maps the API levels to Android OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should't.. And Android 4.0 has different hardware rquirement and latest Api s which are not supported by 2.1 .. so you won't be allowed to do that..

Comment: But that's only assuming he's using APIs that aren't available in 2.2.1.

Comment: @WaynnLue .. Yes definitely.. but its not preferred right.. he can install it in 2.x devices assuming he has not used anything specific to 4.x..

Comment: ya am using action bars and all that stuff

Comment: @sandy... how should i do it then should i rebuilt it wit 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Android support forward compatibility. that is you can install application programmed with API 1.5 to a phone above that API, but you cannot install an application 4.0.3 to a phone below that API. Sandy has quoted down the reasons why you cannot install below that API